# How to keep number comma separated and font smaller in R

Tags: r, html-table, dplyr

For the following dataframe, I want the values which are in `()` to be a comma-separated and font should be little smaller than which are there out side the `()` value.

```
ID      A1        B1         C1          Sum
RE-01   1 (10000)  2 (15000)  4 (55000)  80,000
RE-02   0          2 (25000)  2 (40000)  65,000
```

I need to make the values in `()` to be comma separated with font 1 size smaller than the value out side the `()`.

I'm using below code, but it didn't work.

```
Table<-htmlTable(DF,  
              ctable=c("solid","double"),
              align="lcc",
              col.rgroup = c("none", "#F9FAF0"),
              col.columns = c("none", "#F1F0FA"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that with the package `tableHTML` and the function `prettyNum` like this:

```
DF <- read.table(text = "ID      A1        B1         C1          Sum
                         RE-01 '1 (10000)'  '2 (15000)'  '4 (55000)'  80,000
                         RE-02   0          '2 (25000)'  '2 (40000)'  65,000", header =TRUE)


library(tableHTML)
library(dplyr)

add_font <- function(x) {
  x <- gsub('\\(', '\\(<font size="-1">', x)
  x <- gsub('\\)', '</font>\\)', x)
  return(prettyNum(x, big.mark = ','))
}

DF %>% 
  mutate(A1 = add_font(A1),
         B1 = add_font(B1),
         C1 = add_font(C1)) %>% 
  tableHTML(rownames = FALSE, 
            escape = FALSE,
            widths = rep(100, 5)) %>% 
  add_theme('scientific')
```

you would get:

[image]

Comment: Geeting Error `Error in function_list[[k]](value) : could not find function "add_theme"`

Comment: you probably have an older version of the `tablHTML` package, either install version 2.0.0 or remove `add_ theme` and use `theme = 'scientific' ` inside `tableHTML`

Comment: Thanks:), One small issue, It also converted the date occurs in first column with comma separated (i.e 2015-01-01 changed to 2,015-01-01).

Comment: oops! my bad! that's because I used `mutate_all`, you can use `mutate` or `mutate_if` and change only the columns  you want

Comment: While running `mutate(A1 = add_font(A1),
         B1 = add_font(B1),
         C1 = add_font(C1))` this line of code it creates additional `A1`, `B1` and `C1` variable in `html` one without comma and one with comma.

Comment: I just ran the same code (by copy and paste) and it worked just fine, do you mean that you are getting columns with duplicated names (i.e., two columns called `A1`)? did you change something in the code, like the original names in the dataframe for example?

Comment: Nothing changed, I'm getting new column with name like `A3 <- add_font(A3)`.

Comment: aha, ok! don't use the assignment symbol `<-` inside `mutate`, use the equal sign `= `, i.e., `A3 = add_font(A3)`

Comment: Thanks, My Bad ;)

Comment: Could you please guide a little bit here how to keep first column `ID` left aligned??

Comment: The fastest way I can think of is using the `ID` column as row names, you can test that by adding `tibble::column_to_rownames(var = 'ID')` between mutate and `tableHTML`, the other option would be to remove the pre-defined theme (`add_theme('scientific')`) and define you own which can be achieved with the `add_css_ ... ` family of functions, they are pretty easy to use, if you like you can take a look at the [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tableHTML/vignettes/examples.html)